# How to format a number 2 decimal places in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, currency, helper

I am trying to format a number to either a currency or 2 decimal places within a rails helper (app/helpers/emails_helper.rb)

```
module EmailsHelper
  def email_message(invoice)
    message = "PO: #{invoice.po_number}\nAmount: #{number_to_currency(invoice.total)}"
    return message
  end
end
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
undefined method `number_to_currency' for #<EmailsController:0x00000102b88640>
```

I'm assuming this is because the file is a rb and not an erb but not sure how to handle.

Comment: While printing does `%0.2f` work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing the `NumberHelper` module:

```
module EmailsHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  ...
end
```